# Trying to install matplotlib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I try this in terminal:

`pip install matplotlib`

And it says:

Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252

Comment: could you add the screenshot of the whole error log, there doesn't seem to be enough data here to help.

Comment: Are you able to install other things beside matplotlib?